# minicom trouble connecting to device through serial port

Tags: minicom

I am trying to talk to a device through a RS-232 9pin serial connection using minicom. When connected, the device should take UTF-8 commands and return UTF-8 messages. I am using an FDTI RS-232 to USB adapter. The Bps/Par/Bits for my device are 9600 8N1. I have enabled local echo and added CRLF as required by my device. The device is on port /dev/ttyUSB0

```
$ dmesg | grep ttyUSB0
[64986.995219] usb 1-3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
```

My minirc.dfl file reads

```
pu port             /dev/ttyUSB0
pu baudrate         9600
pu mdialpre         
pu mdialsuf         
pu mdialpre2        
pu mdialsuf2        
pu mdialpre3        
pu mdialsuf3        
pu mhangup          
pu rtscts           No 
pu localecho        Yes
pu addlinefeed      Yes
pu addcarreturn     Yes
```

When I run minicom and type a command to the device, I get no response.

```
Welcome to minicom 2.7.1

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Dec 23 2019, 02:06:26.
Port /dev/ttyUSB0, 16:22:25

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys

>cg 
**(should be a response here)**
```

I have built a loopback RS-232 9pin connector and confirmed that the UTF-8 commands from my minicom terminal are being sent out properly.

Strangely I have been able to connect to the device using the Tera-Term terminal emulator on a windows virtual machine on my computer. Emulating at VT100 terminal and including CRLF and local echo I get the desired response.

```
>cg
temp. CG 37 d
```

I am a bit stumped about why I can connect to the device through the Tera-Term terminal emulator, but not through minicom. Please let me know your thoughts! My ubuntu version is

Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal